# mysql server install on WSL2 Ubuntu machine error

Tags: server, mysql, laravel

I have a fresh install of a WSL2 Ubuntu from windows store, I'm creating a Laravel site with docker and I need to install mysql-server.  I keep running into this issue when installing -

```
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                                         [ OK ]
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
mysqld is running as pid 20452
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                                         [ OK ]
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
mysqld is running as pid 20986
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm a complete novice so forgive any info not provided, I can find any necessary if required.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the full output, its unclear what are you trying to run.

Comment: Also please post how and what you are trying to run. You mentioned WSL, MySQL, Docker and Laravel. But it is unclear what you are trying to achieve, what you really have, what command you are running, and where you are running said command.